# what ${source_elasticsearch} is in Elasticsearch docker file

Tags: elasticsearch, dockerfile

in Elasticsearch docker file:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7.1/distribution/docker/src/docker/Dockerfile

I found line 25:
${source_elasticsearch}
what is this in docker file? why need this ? how does it used and worked?

in line 27:
RUN tar zxf /opt/${elasticsearch}
where is ${elasticsearch} defined?

Answer (score 1):

Using `${variable_name}` in a Dockerfile performs [environment replacement](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement).

In this case `source_elasticsearch` and `elasticsearch` seem to be defined in [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7.1/distribution/docker/build.gradle). While `elasticsearch` is set to the name of a tarball of a specific version of Elasticsearch, `source_elasticsearch` is used to copy or download that tarball.